# Converting 10-digit char data to DB2 BIGINT-type using DFSORT

Tags: db2, mainframe, dfsort

I want to convert a 10-digit character field which contains numeric data to an 8-byte binary to insert into a DB2 BIGINT field.

```
INPUT
-------
1531245800ABC
1531457890DEF

OUTPUT
-------
<8 byte numeric data>ABC
<8 byte numeric data>DEF
```

Load card

```
LOAD DATA                      
LOG NO                       
REPLACE                      
UNICODE  CCSID(01208,00000,00000)
SORTDEVT SYSDA               
SORTNUM 12                   
INTO TABLE                   
<TABLE-NAME>                
KEEPDICTIONARY               
(                               
QUOTEID   POSITION (1) 
BIGINT   
,                              
GEO                             
POSITION (     9  )  CHAR MIXED(3))
```

Comment: `CAST(fld AS BIGINT)` returns a BIGINT

Comment: I have this data in ps(mainframe) file , so I want to do it using dfsort!

Comment: You can do the CAST on the load, you don't need the data in the internal DB2 format. Unless you can say why.

Comment: Is it possible in load card ?Got error while doing that! Edited the question with load card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DFSORT symbols, to make things easier for you and future users:

```
//TOBIGINT EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYMNAMES DD * 
INPUT-CHARACTER-NUMERIC,1,10,ZD 
INPUT-CHARACTER-REST,*,3,CH 
//SYMNOUT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 

  INREC BUILD=(INPUT-CHARACTER-NUMERIC,
                TO=BI, 
                LENGTH=8, 
               INPUT-CHARACTER-REST) 
//SORTIN   DD * 
1531245800ABC 
1531457890DEF
```

Or traditional coding of start, length, type:

```
//TOBIGINT EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 

  INREC BUILD=(1,10,ZD, 
                TO=BI, 
                LENGTH=8, 
                11,3) 
//SORTIN   DD * 
1531245800ABC 
1531457890DEF
```

Output is X'000000005B44F4E8' followed by ABC and X'000000005B483162' followed by DEF.